# rsync not copying my file from remote server

Tags: rsync

I have two VM's : `dev`  and `prod`.

I want to use rsync to copy dump file from `prod` and then restore it on `dev`. I'm using this command to copy:

```
rsync -rave user@ip:/home/user/dumps /home/anotheruser/workspace/someapp/dumps
```

The same thing successfully copies static files (.html, .css) from another directory, but in this case only the folder itself is created but **without** the file:

```
/home/anotheruser/workspace/someapp/dumps
```

but I'm expecting:

```
/home/anotheruser/workspace/someapp/dumps/dumpfile
```

What is going wrong? `dumpfile` exists there `user@ip:/home/user/dumps/dumpfile`.

Comment: what do you think `-e` does? do you really want to create a subfolder `dumps` inside your destination folder `dumps`

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is probably this:

```
rsync -av user@ip:/home/user/dumps/ /home/anotheruser/workspace/someapp/dumps/
```

I've

- removed the `r` because it's implied by the `a` anyway.
- removed the `e` because that was probably your problem; it requires a parameter that you haven't given.
- added the `/` at the end of the pathnames to make sure they're treated as directories.